# How to use gacutil in ASPnet?

Tags: asp.net, system, gacutil

I found that I do not have `System.net.http.dll` in `GAC` folder in windows. Not sure how I lost it. So I tried installing it using `gacutil.exe` in ASP.net folder following the [instructions](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/app-domains/how-to-install-an-assembly-into-the-gac#global-assembly-cache-tool).

But I get errors due to spaces in the links.

I tried running gacutil from its directory as well as in GAC folder. Both got  similar errors.

```
C:\Program Files (x86)\Reference Assemblies\Microsoft\Framework\.NETFramework\v4.7.2>gacutil -i C:\Program Files (x86)\Reference Assemblies\Microsoft\Framework\.NETFramework\v4.7.2\System.Net.Http.dll
'gacutil' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
operable program or batch file.

C:\Program Files (x86)\Reference Assemblies\Microsoft\Framework\.NETFramework\v4.7.2>C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft SDKs\Windows\v10.0A\bin\NETFX 4.7.2 Tools\gacutil -i System.Net.Http.dll
'C:\Program' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
operable program or batch file.

C:\Program Files (x86)\Reference Assemblies\Microsoft\Framework\.NETFramework\v4.7.2>C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft SDKs\Windows\v10.0A\bin\NETFX 4.7.2 Tools\gacutil -i System.Net.Http.dll
'C:\Program' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
operable program or batch file.
```

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: You should use double quotes " like `C:\Program Files (x86)\Reference Assemblies\Microsoft\Framework\.NETFramework\v4.7.2>"C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft SDKs\Windows\v10.0A\bin\NETFX 4.7.2 Tools\gacutil" -i System.Net.Http.dll`. But it is always better to reinstall the complete framework because you may not know what else is missing.

Comment: I reinstalled VS 2019 back. but I still get "C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft SDKs\Windows\v10.0A\bin\NETFX 4.7.2 Tools>gacutil.exe /i "C:\Program Files (x86)\Reference Assemblies\Microsoft\Framework\.NETFramework\v4.7.2\System.Net.Http.dll"
Microsoft (R) .NET Global Assembly Cache Utility.  Version 4.0.30319.0
Copyright (c) Microsoft Corporation.  All rights reserved.
Failure adding assembly to the cache:   An attempt was made to load a program with an incorrect format." 
C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft SDKs\Windows\v10.0A\bin\NETFX 4.7.2 Tools>"

Comment: https://blog.lextudio.com/the-rough-history-of-referenced-assemblies-7d752d92c18c Referenced assemblies are not qualified.